# Windows Backup / wbadmin errors | Source: SPP | Event id: 16389 | Increase SPP CreateTimeout?

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-event-log, vss, sql-server-2014, wbadmin

After a reboot we encounter while the first backup (wbadmin) on a Windows Server 2016  these errors in the eventlog:

- Source: SPP
- Event ID 16389
- Details: The writer's timeout expired between the Freeze and Thaw events (0x800423f2)

**Weak hardware**
 
The server has only sata drives and the controller has no (buffered) cache (Dell T130; H330 controller).

**Errors only after reboot**
The errors occour while backing up MSSQL databases. We also encounter SQLWRITER errors and errors from the SQL Server itself while the backup is running. But the backup itself completes without prompting any error and until the next reboot the following backups are perfomed without any errors in the eventlog.

In the `errorlog of the sql server` I can see for every database:

```
2018-11-02 01:16:37.34 Backup      BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE <name of database> Check the backup application log for detailed messages.
```

`vssadmin list writers`: All writers report stable and no errors

**Possible soulution?**
We found hints to increase the SPP "CreateTimeout" to 20 minutes

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP\CreateTimeout
```

Is this an appropriate way to solve the problems?

May this cause any other problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this Microsoft Document: [Windows Server Backup failed ....](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2011/08/01/windows-server-backup-failed-to-backup-with-error-0x81000101/)

And changed "CreateTimeout":

> Resolution:

> - Run regedit.exe and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP`
> - Create a new Registry value of type DWORD with name `CreateTimeout`
> - Change value to 12000000 (2*10*60*1000 = 20 mins) in decimal

Since that, even after reboots, no errors are reported in the eventlog and the sql server logs.

Comment: Note that 12000000 is 3.3 hours. If you want 20 minutes, assuming the value is in milliseconds, the value would be 1200000 (five zeros). https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2023/05/vss-createtimeout-and-the-persistence-of-a-typo/